# p5js - can't create more than 1 object in draw()

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to create a series of objects that are groups of ellipses to form a line. I can create 1 line ok; however, when I try to introduce a second, it does not show.

If I then proceed to remove the instances of `string1` from the `draw()` method, the second string (`string2`) will now show in the correct area.

For some reason, I can not have both together. I've tried adding other instances of objects that use ellipses from the p5 examples and it works fine, so I'm really not sure what I'm missing here.

Below is my JavaScript, I have created the object 'Harp' in the `setup()` method and displayed/animated it in the `draw()` method.

```
let strings = [];
let visualIncrement = 80;
let initYcoord = -10;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  string1 = new Harp(visualIncrement, initYcoord);
  string2 = new Harp(visualIncrement + 360, initYcoord);
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(51);
  string1.move();
  string1.display();
  string2.move();
  string2.display();
}

function Harp(xpos, ypos) {
  this.xpos = xpos; // x position on screen
  this.ypos = ypos; // y position on screen

  this.yspacing = 0.5; // spacing between lines
  this.theta = 0.0; // start angle
  this.period = 100; // pixels before the wave repeats
  this.yvalues; // array for height values
  this.inputAmp = 5.5; // modulated value required for amplitude

  this.w = height;
  this.dx = (TWO_PI * this.period) * this.yspacing;
  this.yvalues = new Array(floor(this.w/this.yspacing));

  this.move = function() {
    this.theta = this.theta += map(400, 0, windowWidth, 0.0, 1.6);
    this.amplitude = map(this.inputAmp, 0, 400, 0.0, 500);
    this.dx = map(80, 0, 400, 0.0, 1.0);

    this.x = this.theta;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.yvalues.length; i++) {
      this.yvalues[i] = sin(this.x)*this.amplitude;
      this.x+=this.dx;
    }
  }
  this.display = function() {
    fill(255);
    translate(this.xpos, this.ypos);
    for(let x = 0; x < this.yvalues.length; x++) {
      strokeWeight(20);
      stroke(255);
      translate(0, 9);
      ellipse(height/80+this.yvalues[x], x*this.yspacing, 0.2, 0.02);
      // ellipse(this.xpos, this.ypos, 0.2, 0.02);
    }
  }
}
```

Also have a CodePen here: https://codepen.io/joeqj2/pen/gBLPvg

I've never come across this problem and completely stumped by it, can't find anything online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a call to `translate()` inside your `display()` function. Keep in mind that **translations stack.** For example:

```
translate(100, 0);
translate(0, 100);
ellipse(0, 0, 20, 20);
```

This code will draw an ellipse at `100, 100`, because the calls to `translate()` stack.

Back to your code, when you draw the first line, you call `translate()` to move where you're drawing the line. Then to draw the second line, you call `translate()` again. But note that this second call to `translate()` is done on top of that first call, so your second line ends up somewhere off the edge of the screen. This is also why your second line shows up if you remove your first line.

There are a couple solutions to this:

- You could eliminate the calls to `translate()` and use the coordinates in your drawing directly.
- Or you could call the `push()` and `pop()` functions to isolate the translations for each line.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push).

Comment: Wow thank you Kevin you're a lifesaver, the push and pop methods worked perfectly! Looking back at the reference I can see this was mentioned but I overlooked it.